# Como saber se um interseção contém outra interseção?

Tags: lógica

Se `I` e `J` são dois conjuntos formados por interseções,
como saber se `I` contém `J`, sabendo que:

- `I` = i<sub>1</sub> ∩ i<sub>2</sub> ... ∩ i<sub>n</sub>
- `J` = j<sub>1</sub> ∩ j<sub>2</sub> ... ∩ j<sub>n</sub>
- nem `I` nem `J` são vazios, por consequência nenhum i<sub>x</sub> ou j<sub>x</sub> o são

Eu sei que a resposta é ternária, podendo ser Verdadeira, Falsa ou Indefinida...
pra falar a verdade eu já sei parte da resposta, mas como eu sou uma só mente limitada,
pode ser que ainda falte algum caso que eu não esteja conseguindo visualizar. Talvez alguém com uma base matemática mais sólida possa colocar um ponto final nisso.

**Edição 1: Operações disponíveis**

Os conjuntos não são enumeráveis. É possível usar operadores entre os conjuntos. Na minha interface tenho definidas `Contains(other)`, `Intersects(other)` e `IsEmpty()`, sendo que cada operação pode retornar um terceiro valor além de *Sim* e *Não*, que é *Indefinido*... mas para os testes feitos entre os conjuntos `ix` e `jx` podemos assumir uma resposta booleana, pois o valor indefinido seria simplesmente propagado. Também há operações que retornam conjuntos `Intersection(other)` e `Union(other)`.

Resumindo:

- não é possível enumerar
- existem operações de teste cada uma retornando *Sim*, *Não* e *Indefinido*:

  - `Contains(other)`
  - `Intersects(other)`
  - `IsEmpty()`
- existem operações que retornam outros conjuntos

  - `Intersection(other)`
  - `Union(other)`

Comment: O que se sabe sobre os conjuntos `ix` e `jx`, e o que é testável em relação a esses conjuntos? Por exemplo, se todos os conjuntos fossem finitos e enumeráveis, seria simplesmente questão de ver elemento por elemento... Por outro lado, se isso não for possível, mas você puder estabelecer predicados em relação aos elementos (ex.: `i2` contém `j4`, sim ou não?), quais são esses predicados, e a que elementos eles se aplicam? Eu posso por exemplo testar se `ix` faz interseção com `jx`, mas ao mesmo tempo não posso testar se `ix ∩ iy` faz interseção com `jz`? Quais são as restrições aplicáveis?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Atualizei a questão com informações adicionais sobre as operações possíveis. Sobre testar se`ix ∩ iy` faz interseção com `jz`, é possível... vai depender da instância retornada pela operação `ix ∩ iy`.

Answer (score 4):

Aqui vai o que eu acredito ser a resposta, ou pelo menos, parte dela:

### `I` contém `J` com certeza

Uma das formas de ter certeza que `I` contém `J` está abaixo <sup>(talvez existam mais condições, eu não tenho certeza)</sup>

- todos os i<sub>n</sub> contiverem pelo menos um dos j<sub>n</sub>

  Note que a primeira interseção contém a segunda interseção em todos os casos apresentados abaixo.

  1. exemplo com 3 conjuntos formando `I` e 3 formando `J`

     [image: exemplo com 3 conjuntos em I e 3 em J] => [image: resultado]
  2. exemplo com 3 conjuntos formando `I` e 2 formando `J`

     [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] => [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
  3. exemplo com 2 conjuntos formando `I` e 3 formando `J`

     [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] => [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- não basta que todos os j<sub>n</sub> estejam contidos em um dos i<sub>n</sub>. Veja um contra-exemplo:

  [image: contra-exemplo] => [image: resultado]

  Como é possível ver todos os j<sub>n</sub> estão contidos em algum i<sub>n</sub>, entretanto `I` não contém `J`
- a negativa não garante que `I` não contém `J`. Veja um contra-exemplo:

  [image: contra-exemplo da negativa] => [image: resultado do contra-exemplo]

  Como é possível ver, nem todos os i<sub>n</sub> contém algum j<sub>n</sub>, entretanto `I`contém `J` mesmo assim. No caso apresentado acima

### `I` não contém `J` com certeza

Só sei de uma forma de garantir que `I` não contém `J`:

- qualquer i<sub>n</sub> não possuir interseção com qualquer j<sub>n</sub>

  Se qualquer i<sub>x</sub> for disjunto de qualquer j<sub>k</sub>, como `I` é subconjunto desse i<sub>x</sub> e `J` é subconjunto desse j<sub>k</sub>, então `I` e `J` são também disjuntos.

  [image: disjuntos]

  Nesse exemplo os conjuntos delineados de vermelho, são disjuntos, e portanto a interseção amarela e a interseção azul são também disjuntas.
- a negativa desta não garante que `I` contém `J`:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

  A pesar de existir interseção entre todos os i e todos os j, `I` não contém `J`... `I` intercepta `J`, mas não contém. A interseção amarela, não contém a interseção azul.

### Indefinidos

Os casos que não é possível ter certeza ficam indefinidos. É possível que haja mais casos em que seja possível ter certeza, tanto positiva quanto negativa. Mas eu não tenho como provar isso matematicamente.